# How do I trade Pokémon between two emulated generation 4 games?

Tags: emulation, pokemon-fourth-generation

I want to know how to trade Pokemon between 2 Emulated generation 4 games like Platinum and Heart Gold, but as far as my research showed it is only possible through GTS, which is shutdown, so I can't trade in emulators in gen-4 games.

Does anyone know a way to make it possible without faking it? (Faking it means using stuff like *PokeGen* or spawning the Pokémon you want to trade in a route through cheats)

Some Things to know:

- I have a Laptop
- I have a Phone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MelonDS emulator should work with union room but from my experience, it's unstable. You might have to resort to online trading like GTS or wi-fi club which have been resurrected by players and can be used if you connect with the right DNS (even mystery gifts work with this). Check out pokemon classic network for example, that seems to be the most reliable one.

Comment: thank you, my first try it BSed (blue-screened) me, second try i tweaked the settings and still nothing, third try i changed the DNS to PokéClassic Network, and enabled the JIT compiler and then it BSed me. i tried again and it finally worked! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Some emulators offer connectivity features to connect to each other through means other than the internet (such as infrared or NFC, depending on the exact system you're emulating). If your emulator has this, you can use local trade. This is the same thing you'd do if you played on the original console and had a friend with theirs come over to trade.

Other than that, there is no way of legitimately trading between games which have been excluded from the GTS by now (which includes everything up to Gen VI at the time I'm writing this answer).

Comment: Can You Point out some emulators that have the ability to trade that way?(sorry for major time Differnce As i am In a Differnet Time zone)

Comment: I haven't used any that have the feature, I've only seen the feature on several roadmaps a couple of years ago and expect it to be finished for at least some of them (or new ones). In short, I sadly can't, but searching the internet should yield some results.